# SQL Incorrect syntax near '> when calculating age from date of birth

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I am trying to get age while calculating it from dob (DATE) and compare it whether is it greater than 64.However it gets an error Incorrect syntax near '>'.

Below are the code

```
sqlStr.Append("SELECT count(CustomerRace) as CustomerCount, CustomerRace");
        sqlStr.Append("FROM Customer");
        sqlStr.Append("WHERE SELECT DATEDIFF(YYYY,CustomerDOB,GETDATE()) >  64");
        sqlStr.Append("GROUP BY CustomerRace");
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this, hope this will work for you.

```
sqlStr.Append("SELECT count(CustomerRace) as CustomerCount, CustomerRace ");
        sqlStr.Append("FROM Customer ");
        sqlStr.Append("WHERE DATEDIFF(YY,CustomerDOB,GETDATE()) >  64 ");
        sqlStr.Append("GROUP BY CustomerRace");
```

Comment: I guess you should put space after each statement?

Comment: I tried changing to code however it shows Incorrect syntax near 'DATEDIFF'.

Comment: Use this one DATEDIFF(yy,CustomerDOB,GETDATE())

Comment: Still having the same issue

Comment: show exactly error message then i guess what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Datediff function incorrect parameter count.Use below one. And also if you use mysql GETDATE() function will not work use now() to get current date;

```
   sqlStr.Append("SELECT count(CustomerRace) as CustomerCount, CustomerRace");
        sqlStr.Append("FROM Customer");
        sqlStr.Append("WHERE DATEDIFF(CustomerDOB, now()) >  64");
        sqlStr.Append("GROUP BY CustomerRace");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 sqlStr.Append("SELECT count(CustomerRace) as CustomerCount, CustomerRace");

        sqlStr.Append("FROM Customer");

        sqlStr.Append("WHERE DATEDIFF(yy,CustomerDOB,GETDATE()) >  64");

        sqlStr.Append("GROUP BY CustomerRace");
```

which is still having the same issue